# Relativistic charged particle in a constant uniform electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, relativity

I'm doing some special relativity exercises. I have to find $x(t)$ and $v(t)$ of a charged particle left at rest in $t=0$ in an external constant uniform electric field $\vec{E}=E_{0} \hat{i}$, then with that velocity I should find the Liénard–Wiechert radiated power.

I will show you what I did but I feel that it is wrong.

We should solve the equation of motion given by

$$
\tag{1}\frac{dp^{\mu}}{d\tau} = \frac{q}{c} F^{\mu \nu}u_{\nu}
$$

The four-velocity is given by

$$
u^{\mu} = (u^{0},u^{1},u^{2},u^{3}) = \gamma (c,v^{1},v^{2},v^{3})
$$

where $v^{\alpha}$ are the components of the three-velocity. The four-momentum is

$$
p^{\mu} = mu^{\mu}
$$

This will give us four equtions where two of them will give a constant velocities and the other two are

$$
\tag{2}\frac{d\gamma}{d\tau} = -\frac{qE_{0}}{mc^{2}}\gamma v_{1}
$$

$$
\tag{3}\frac{d\gamma}{d\tau} v_{1} + \gamma \frac{dv_{1}}{d\tau} = \frac{qE_{0}}{m} \gamma
$$

Replacing $(2)$ in $(3)$ gives

$$
\tag{4}\frac{dv_{1}}{d\tau} = -\frac{qE_{0}}{mc^{2}} (v_{1})^{2} + \frac{qE_{0}}{m}
$$

The solution of the ODE $(4)$ gives something like

$$
\tag{5}v_{1}(\tau) = A\tanh{(B\tau)}
$$

This component of the three-velocity is in terms of the proper time $\tau$ and the problem ask me to find the velocity in terms of the time $t$. So my attempt was to solve

$$
\tag{6}\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \gamma (\tau) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{(v_{1}(\tau))^{2}}{c^{2}}}}
$$

and then replacing this solution for  $\tau$ in $(5)$. But the solution of $(6)$ is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2Fsqrt(1%20-%20a%5E2*tanh(bx)%5E2)). Which doesn't make any sense to me.

I think that I'm misunderstanding something or missing something that will give me a easier solution to this problem. I thought it because in the Liénard–Wiechert radiated power I sould do $dv_{1}/dt$ which is almost impossible to do it without WolframAlpha.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. Please use that tag on homework problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the initial conditions,

\begin{align*}
  a_{0} &= \frac{qE_{0}}{m} \\
  v &= c\tanh \frac{a_{0} \tau}{c} \\
  \gamma &= \cosh \frac{a_{0} \tau}{c} \\
  &= \frac{dt}{d\tau} \\
  t &= \int_{0}^{\tau} \cosh \frac{a_{0} \tau}{c} \,  d\tau \\
  &= \frac{c}{a_{0}} \sinh \frac{a_{0} \tau}{c} \\
  \frac{a_{0} t}{c} &= \sinh \frac{a_{0} \tau}{c} \\
  v &= \frac{a_{0} t}{\sqrt{1+\left( \dfrac{a_{0}t}{c} \right)^{2}}} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, what are you saying is that I forgotten to use equation $(2)$ to recover what $\gamma$ looks like right?

Comment: Closely, sometimes it's useful to check your results with the classical limit and relativistic limit.  For $t\approx 0$, $v\approx a_{0} t$ whereas $t\to \infty$, $v\to c$.

Comment: So the Lorentz factor $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$ is only true when the velocity is a constant?

Comment: What I mean is try to fit the integration constants $A$ and $B$ by looking at $\tau \to 0$, $v\to AB\tau$ and $\tau \to \infty$, $v\to A$ you immediately get the result.  Actually, I'd rather formulate directly as $qE_{0}=\gamma^3 ma \,$ so that $$\frac{qE_{0}t}{m}=\int_{0}^{v} \frac{dv}{\left( 1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{3/2}}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$