# How does an uniformly accelerated particle see the world in 1+1D?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames

Let's consider an observer $O$ associated with an inertial referential frame $R$ in a flat spacetime (no gravitational field). This observer is looking at an uniformly accelerated particle $P$ moving in a constant direction (no Thomas precession). The coordinates of the particle in $R$ are ($x$,$t$). The constant acceleration of the particle is called $a$, I define it here as a **coordinate** acceleration ($a = d^2x/d^2t$) and **not** a proper acceleration. Therefore in this problem the proper acceleration is **not** constant, one cannot use the Rindler coordinates.

The equation of motion of the particle $P$ view from $R$ is,
$$x(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2+v_{0}t+x_{0}$$

What is the equation of motion of the observer $O$ view from the particle $P$ in its non inertial referential $R'$ ?

You can use $(x',t')$ as the coordinates of $O$ in the referential $R'$, and $\tau$ the proper time of $R$, $\tau'$ the proper time of $R'$.

Answer (score 0):

[**Rindler spacetime**](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates)

\begin{align}
  F' &= m_0 a_0 \\[5pt]
  \begin{pmatrix} t \\ x \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \left( \frac{c}{a_0}+\frac{\xi}{c} \right) \sinh \frac{a_0\tau}{c} \\
    \left( \frac{c^2}{a_0}+\xi \right) \cosh \frac{a_0\tau}{c}-\frac{c^2}{a_0}
  \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  \begin{pmatrix} \tau \\ \xi \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{c}{a_0} \tanh^{-1} \frac{ct}{\frac{c^2}{a_0}+x} \\
    -\frac{c^2}{a_0}+\sqrt{\left( \frac{c^2}{a_0}+x \right)^2-(ct)^2}
  \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  ds^2 &= (c^2+a_0\xi)^2 d\tau^2-d\xi^2 \\[5pt]
  v &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \\[5pt]
    &= c\tanh \frac{a_0\tau}{c} \\[5pt]
    &= \frac{a_0 t}{\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{a_0 t}{c} \right)^2}} \\[5pt]
  \gamma &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \\[5pt]
  &= \cosh \frac{a_0\tau}{c} \\[5pt]
  &= \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{a_0 t}{c} \right)^2} \\[5pt]
  \frac{dx}{dt} &=
  \frac{c\frac{d\xi}{d\tau}+\left( 1+\frac{a_0\xi}{c^2} \right) v}
       {\left( 1+\frac{a_0\xi}{c^2} \right)+\frac{v}{c^2} \frac{d\xi}{d\tau}}
  \tag{velocity addition}
\end{align}

See also another situation [**here**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316282/relativistic-charged-particle-in-a-constant-uniform-electric-field/316358#316358).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However I am sorry to not understand how it does answer my question, what is the equation of motion for $x'(t')$ ?

Comment: Actually, $(\xi,\tau)=(x',t')$.  The metric is governed by proper acceleration $a$, proper time $\tau$.

Comment: In my problem, $a$ is the coordinate acceleration, not the proper acceleration. So your $a$ is not my $a$, correct ?

Comment: Notation revised

Comment: Knowing that $a_{0}=a\gamma^3$, do you agree that your answer is:

$x'(t) = -\frac{c^2}{a\gamma^3}+\sqrt{\left( \frac{c^2}{a\gamma^3}+x \right)^2-(ct)^2}$

Comment: I am sorry Ng Chung Tak, but I believe Rindler coordinates are working only for a constant **proper** acceleration. In my problem, the coordinate acceleration is constant, but the **proper** acceleration varies, so one cannot use the Rindler coordinates !

Comment: You **never** have constant acceleration forever, otherwise the velocity will exceed $c$.